# Calculating a limit using dominated convergence theorem

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to show that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [-a,0]$,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \int_{0}^{1} x z^n e^{-xz} dz = \int_{0}^{1} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}  x z^n e^{-xz} dz = 0,$$
using dominated convergence theorem.

My attempt is as follow:

Define $f_x(z) = xz^n e^{-xz}$, then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} f_x(z) = 0 = f(z).$$

To have a dominating function, we have
$$\sup_{z\in[0,1]}|f_x(z) - f(z)| = \sup_{z\in[0,1]}|xz^n e^{-xz}|.$$

But I'm having problems determining a dominating function.

I need a hint about where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is that your function is continuous.

Comment: ok so if we define $\sup_{z\in[0,1]}|f_x(z)-f(z)| = \sup_{z\in[0,1]}|g_x(z)|$, then $g_x(z) =  xz^ne^{-xz}$ for all $z\in[0,1]$, then $g_x(0) = 0$ and $g_x(1)=xe^{-x}$. But how can I show it converges to 0 as $x\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: If you are looking at $x\to0$, what's the role of $n$?